# Angular Router: Why do we need both: guards and events?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Could somebody explain me what is conceptual difference between events and guards for Angular Router?

Comment: What are hooks?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think Stepan means guards, not hooks.

Comment: yes, thank you @Dinistro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Guards are executed before a route change happends to decide whether this route change is allowed, or do redirects, or load data.
- Events notify about route changes that have happened.